# How to decrypt files from installed apk file in cordova application

Tags: android, cordova, encryption, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have one cordova application, in that i wants to encrypt my localstorage and other important data files to secure it.

i have tried installing Crosswalk plugin & some other options as well.
But none of them are working as expected.

Please give some good documentation or any example or any plugin to secure the app data.

Thanks,
sopo

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused. Your title is saying that you are willing to decrypt an apk but the question is asking to encrypt data for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this or something similar: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-safe

Comment: Thanks Steve, for reply. whats the proper way to add files localstorage path till installed directory. is it "file:/storage/Android/data/data/com.myapp.app/app_webview/'Local Storage'/file__0.localstorage" ?. because currently my app is not working proper after adding this plugin. i think its because of improper path. can you please guide over here

Comment: the second option, which i have tried is ""data/data/com.myapp.app/app_webview/'Local Storage'/file__0.localstorage"". with this also facing same issue. do you have any good reference for finding this